# Typescript lazy load ember modules with requirejs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, typescript, requirejs, lazy-loading

We are in process of splitting our large ember app into logical chunks and delay load few of the modules to improve performance.

We have an **entry** which in turn recursively includes all dependencies and creates one big rjs optimized file during build process. We want to load few core components and the routes during initial load and delay load everything else.

We want to nest our require calls inside **route** and use **beforeModelHook** to load dependent controllers, templates, components as specified in this guide http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2014/10/02/Lazy-loading-es6-modules-with-emberjs/

Now the problem is if we skip import statement

```
import mycontroller = require("mycontroller")
```

and use nested require

```
beforeModel() {
   require(["mycontroller"])
   ...
}
```

typescript fails to list **mycontroller** as dependency when compiled. How to resolve this issue?

What are other ways of achieving improving performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> typescript fails to list mycontroller as dependency when compiled. How to resolve this issue

You need to use the imported type for your file to have a run-time dependency on the module. This is specifically designed to support lazy loading scenarios

## Docs

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you